# Query post by meta key of another table

Tags: posts, query, table

Im using event calendar plugin where I can set event date for posts and it shows in calendar widget. Everything is working as inteded but I would also like to query post by event date.

I know how to query posts by meta key but problem is that date meta value is stored in separate table named `wp_ftcalendar_events`. Name of meta key is `start_datetime`. Table starts with post ID so it's shared for both tables.

My question is - Is it possible to make WP query posts by meta key from another table?

[image]

Comment: No, not by default. You would need to use the `posts_*` filters to alter the generated SQL query to include your custom table. I would also contact the plugin author about this issue as I'm sure that this issue has been raised and answered by himself or by someone on his support site or group. ;-)

Comment: There were maybe 2 or 3 similar topics on plugin support page but without any answer. I was trying to find an answer on my own before asking here. Including custom table is beyond my knowledge so I believe I will have to look for another plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to answer your question without having knowledge how the plugin works, how and where the data is stored and the relationship between the posts and this specific data. I believe that if you can supply this exact info in your question, you might get an answer on this, but without this info, I'm afraid that your question, in all probability, will go unanswered